# Why my book uses に in this sentence?

Tags: particle-に

> 私**に**聞こえるように大きい声で話してください

Couldn't it have simply been something like:

> 私**が**聞けるように大きい声で話してください

?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30023/i-found-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86-all-by-itself-is-there-any-difference-in-the-usual-meaning

Comment: duplicate: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/what-is-the-difference-between-%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%BF%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-%E8%81%9E%E3%81%93%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%8D%E3%81%93%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-and-%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%BF%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-%E8%81%9E%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%8D%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B

Comment: Possible duplicate of [が and に interchangeability and difference in meaning](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/%e3%81%8c-and-%e3%81%ab-interchangeability-and-difference-in-meaning)

Comment: @永劫回帰 I'm not convinced - the main point of the other question is that the verb form stays the same. Here it's obvious one is transitive, one is not.

Comment: @macraf Indeed I read too fast and saw 聞こえる in both which lead me to consider it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I recognized as follows for each sentence.

The former sentense, as in your textbook, puts emphasis on the speaker speaking at loud, and he/she doing so would result in his/her voice conveyed to 私, without much effort.  For the reason described in next paragraph, I felt it sounds more polite.

The latter sentence, I felt the emphasis is on the 私 being able to listen the word spoken by the speaker.  This sentense might be less polite than the former because, it seems to more or less connotate that the speaker is asked to speak at loud all for the sake of 私.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same but can have a slightly different nuance in some situations.
The version with に for example is slightly emphasizing the "I":

> Speak loudly so that **I** (as oposed to someone else) can hear it, please.

whereas the が could imply that the person (私) would otherwise have problems understanding what is spoken.

But I think most of the times you could really use both.

Answer (score 0):

- 私に聞こえるように大きい声で話してください  ----- is polite and normal.
- 私が聞けるように大きい声で話してください  ----- is much more direct, and blunt.

Also, as the following examples show, [聞ける is usually not used for physically audible](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%E8%81%9E%E3%81%93%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E3%80%80%E8%81%9E%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%80%80%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E3%80%80%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B.3008887/)

```
(1) 聞こえる
　　努力しなくても、意識しなくても自然に聞こえてくること。
 　　　例文：　うとうとしていると、どこからか、きれいな音楽が聞こえてきた。
 　　　　　　　（上記の例文にて、「聞けた」と言うと間違い。）

(2) 聞ける
　　聞く機会を持つ。周囲の諸条件が整ったおかげで、聞くことができるという意味。
 　　　例文：　有名な指揮者が来日したおかげで、僕は実に素晴らしい演奏が聞けた（聞くことができた）。
```